# How can I reproduce the way a former developer signed our android app?

Tags: android, jar-signing

I have an issue signing my app. When I sign it, and upload it, I get the error "The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version."

Before you ask, yes I'm sure it's the same keystore. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the way my former coworker signed it. I've tried signing it two ways:

1. With jarsigner/zipalign. This results in an apk with a META-INF folder that contains 3 files: MYALIASN.RSA,  MYALIASN.SF, and MANIFEST.MF
2. With eclipse ->export exporting a signed app. This results in an apk with a META-INF folder that contains 3 files: CERT.RSA, CERT.SF, and MANIFEST.MF

I looked in the old apk and saw 5 files in the META-INF directory: MYALIASN.RSA, MYALIASN.SF, CERT.RSA, CERT.SF, and MANIFEST.MF.  I tried simply signing my app with jarsigner after signing with eclipse, which did result in the same five files, but alas, I still got the same error.  What am I missing here? Does anybody have any good advice as to how to reproduce the way it was signed before, or am I doing it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: My first advice would be asking your former co-worker.

Comment: Yes well he said he just signed it with jar signer. But it seems to me there is a second certificate in there. Is that the case or am I signing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what happened for anybody that comes across this.  My coworker had used the apk from the bin folder as the 'unsigned apk' and then signed it as normal. His debug keystore was also embeded in the apk when he first uploaded it. I'm pretty sure that since we can't reproduce his debug keystore that we are out of luck :(

Answer (score 1):

it has to be signed with the same keystore AND the same developer alias

Comment: there is only one alias in the keystore